# Check for parameter TypeError without executing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation

About the following code, how can I know the `TypeError` before execute it? is it possible?

My `p.py` script:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass    

x = X(1)
```

When I compile it, it raises no errors:

```
LM-SHC-00950567:test$ python -m py_compile p.py
LM-SHC-00950567:test$ python -m compileall p.py
```

But when I execute it, it does:

```
LM-SHC-00950567:test$  python p.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = X(1)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I know the TypeError before execute it? is it possible?

With `python` only, *no*, you can't. Python is **a dynamic language**, *not a static one*. It doesn't perform any checks to see whether you have errors before you execute, *it just executes*. It's your fault if you make a conceptual error like you did.

What you can do of course, is use a static checking tool for this. One candidate which has gotten attention recently due to type hints, is [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) , a static checker that, among other cool things, catches these sort of errors.

Running `mypy` on your script yields:

```
(Python3)jim@jim: mypy p.py 
p.py:6: error: Too many arguments for "X"
```

So it caught it without requiring execution.

---

In general though performing checks like these is not what python is about. In python we `try` first and catch `except`ions later (**[`EAFP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)** principle). For example, if your `p.py` script had a line of the form `print(X.i)`, which is an obvious `AttributeError`, instead of checking it it would be better to wrap it in a `try-except`:

```
try:
    print(X.i)
except AttributeError:
    print("X has no attribute i")
```

Comment: As an addendum -- if you're used to having the compiler catch errors like this for you, and you're worried that some might slip through in Python without being caught, then the solution is to write good tests for your software. These can verify that everything functions as it should, and also provide some documentation of how your software is supposed to work. e.g., see http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/

Comment: It is a bit of pity that mypy doesn't support python 2.7 well and my code can't migrate to python 3 so far.

Comment: @zhihuifan unfortunately, yes, this is limited to Py3.5. You could maybe look at **[`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org/)** but I am not certain it provides the checking you need.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible if you know the language construct:
for example in python if you use `**kwargs` python expects you to call that class with `keyword arguments` while creating objects of that class e.g `x = X(value = 25)` your above code would've worked if you used `def __init__(self, *args)` which takes positional arguments(an arbitrary number of arguments), so that's it, hope it helps.

Comment: sure, I know this. but sometimes,  I just forget it. like sometimes I may write str + number.  it is great that we have some handy tools like complier for c++.